# Why my code is running correctly in IDLE, but not in hackerearth?

Tags: python-3.x, syntax-error

I tried to solve my first problem in hackerearth.com, i wrote my code in python 3.10. My program ran perfectly in IDLE, but the same program is giving a wrong output in hackerearth.com. Someone please help me to understand this issue!

```
N = input( )#5
a= input( )#1,1,2,2,4

x=0
y=0
rating=[]#2,2,0,1,0

for j in range(1,len(a)+1):
    for k in range(0,len(a)):
        if(a[k]==j):
            x=x+1
        else:
            continue    
    rating.append(x)
    x=0

rating_max=max(rating)#2
for i in range(0,len(rating)):
    if(rating[i]==rating_max):
        y=y+1
    else:
        continue
print(y)
```

[My code in hackerearth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzy7Q.png)
[The same code gave this output in IDLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUWIM.png)

I just want to understand where is the issue. I tested each step in hackereart.com and I found that this part of the program is not working properly in hackerearth.

```
for j in range(1,len(a)+1):
    for k in range(0,len(a)):
        if(a[k]==j):
            x=x+1
        else:
            continue    
    rating.append(x)
    x=0
```